# USB Printing from android app

Tags: android, printing

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for printing to a USB printer from an Android app, or does this require writing a custom USB driver or something? Most of the information I see on the web concerns either printing via Google Cloud Print or else using low-level USB protocols. I am aiming to write a single-purpose app that communicates directly with a printer to print pages at certain times.